# How to create n plotly shapes (in loop) - python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, shapes

So I am trying to plot n circle shapes in a graph with Plotly. This number n can vary and that's why I cannot create them manually but I need a loop. Is there anyway to do that? to replicate n times this piece of code according to my list indexes?:

```
  'shapes': [
     # Circle to define radius_of_persistence
    {
        'type': 'circle',
        'xref': 'x',
        'yref': 'y',
        'x0': zois_list[0]-radius_of_persistence,
        'y0': zois_list[1]-radius_of_persistence,
        'x1': zois_list[0]+radius_of_persistence,
        'y1': zois_list[1]+radius_of_persistence,
        'line': {
            'color': 'rgba(255, 171, 96, 1)',
        },
    },
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem? The code snippet you gave is not even valid Python on its own.

Comment: The code is not complete, but it is valid. It is a piece of plotly code scheme to plot a circle. So far, I have just added them manually, adding a for loop does not work inside this kind of plotly schemes and I didn't find any post doing the same thing.

Comment: could you provide us a piece of code that we could run on our devices to test before answering? This would help a lot the people trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I already have the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically the only way that I found to create shapes in a loop is to create the json object that represents the "layout" myself. In this way I can include as many entries in the dictionary (layout) as I want.

Answer (score 1):

I created the list of shapes in a loop before updating the layout of the figure, like:

```
shapes = []
    for ind_begin, ind_end in zip(ind_begins, ind_ends):
        shapes.append(go.layout.Shape(
                    type="rect",
                    xref="x",
                    yref="paper",
                    x0=df.iloc[:, 0][ind_begin],
                    y0=0,
                    x1=df.iloc[:, 0][ind_end],
                    y1=1,
                    fillcolor="LightSalmon",
                    opacity=0.5,
                    layer="below",
                    line_width=0,
                ))
    fig.update_layout(
            shapes=shapes
        )
```